# Custom Shapes :Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes, layer-list

I want to draw custom shapes like this-

[image]

I want to make this using xml.I cant seem to understand the use of layer-list and items as they are behaving weirdly. How should I draw the shape like this? Don't expect complete code, just give me idea or point me in the right direction.
Thanks

EDIT : this is the code that i ve tried so far

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="40dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item
    android:right="-100dp"
    android:left="100dp"
    android:top="-100dp"
    android:bottom="-100dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: i hv tried using layer-lists and items inside..but i never get the shape i want

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: i ve made an edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something close

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Outer green rectangle-->
    <item
        android:bottom="150dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ff57fa60" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="140dp"
        android:bottom="100dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- inner white rectangle -->
    <item
        android:bottom="60dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:left="100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="75">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="100dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Comment: sorry but those we actually 2 images...ive made an edit to the question.. i just want the green shape

Comment: OK. I made my final commit of the code just now. It is now exactly like you want. If this helped you, then up vote it and accept it :)